# Setting Web Service ContextPath in NetBeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans

I am using NetBeans to create a Web Service project. I have 3 web services under the project, let's say A, B,C.

I know that under project properties -> Run, you can set your context path there. Let's say I set the contextPath to be /myproject

Now my question is: I want the wsdl for each of my web service to be something like this;

```
http://mydomain/myproject/util/A?wsdl
http://mydomain/myproject/common/B?wsdl
http://mydomain/myproject/document/C?wsdl
```

How do i do that? Do I need to create 3 netbeans project and set 3 different contextpaths to achieve this? Or is there any configuration that can be done for each individual web service?